# How to update not all properties of object?

Tags: nhibernate

How not to update some properties of object with NHibernate?

For example:

```
var user = new User();
user.Id = 5;
user.Name= "afsf";
user.Login = "asdfsf";
```

and password propery by default is `null`,

```
user.Password == null;

.....

session.Update( user )
```

How not to update Password property?

Comment: set update=false  ...........

Comment: But what if i need to update this property in some cases?

Comment: well in that case it wont get updated  :)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the user from database, before updating.

```
var user = session.Get<User>(5);
user.Name="username";
...
session.Update(user);
```

Also, you can map 2 classes, one with info about the user settings, like name, email and so on, and another one with info about the user login, login and password.